# Discord - Sorting through members connected to a VC and giving them roles

Tags: node.js, discord, bots

I'm trying to go through my discord vc "Among Us" and give everyone there the role "In-Game". Currently my code is:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    //let role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "In-Game");
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "In-Game");
    let channels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.parentID === '759363400253308948' && c.type === 'voice');

    if (message.content.startsWith('.rank')) {
        for (const [channelID, channel] of channels) {
            for (const [memberID, member] of channel.members) {
                member.roles.add(role);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I'm not getting error but I'm not getting any results either? Why would that be the case?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem is that your channels variable is empty, therefore when you try to loop on it and loop over members in that channel, nothing happens.
I think the reason for this is your arrow function, which filters for channels childed to a certain parent, returns nothing. `channel.parentID` returns a number but you're comparing it to a string of a number, using `===` which checks for value AND type. Change to `==` (which will check for equalish values, even if the types are different) or remove the quotes.

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    //let role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "In-Game");
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "In-Game");
    let channels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.parentID == '759363400253308948' && c.type === 'voice');

    if (message.content.startsWith('.rank')) {
        for (const [channelID, channel] of channels) {
            for (const [memberID, member] of channel.members) {
                member.roles.add(role);
                //if you want to do anything after the roles have been added, you need to await the above line
                //and make the event function async.
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Note: your bot will need relevant permissions. I believe the ones necessary one:
**Read text channels / view voice channels**: To see what channels a user is in
**Manage roles**: Lets you assign roles to users.